# Whether in mahabharat itself(not in purana), krishna is depicted as makhan chor(stealing butter)?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, critical-edition, critique

Whether in mahabharat, esp. BORI edition(though other edition may also do), krishna is depicted as makhan chor(stealing butter) ?

Please do not give reference of any purana.

Comment: Please use proper English grammer!

Comment: @Wikash_ , your spelling of grammar is wrong, it's 'a' , not 'e'. lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There would not be the stories and leelas of Krishna in Mahabharata because it is the story of Kurus and not Yadu's the dynasty Krishna belonged to.

From Chapter 62 of [Adi Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01063.htm),

> "Janamejaya said, 'O excellent Brahmana, thou hast, indeed, told me, in brief, the history, called Mahabharata, **of the great acts of the Kurus**.

It is the history of the dynasty originated from Bharata. This Bharata is ancestor of Pandavas and Kauravas. Krishna has a role in this but he acts as a kingmaker. The stories and leelas of Krishna since his childhood are explained in the Puranas only. So, his acts will *not* be found in detail in Mahabharata.